# Exercício com matrizes - linguagem c

Tags: c, matriz

o exercício pede o seguinte:
Escreva um programa para ler um inteiro Q (máximo 10 – não é necessário validar). A seguir ler uma matriz de Q linhas e Q colunas. Imprimir as seguintes somas:
• Dos elementos localizados na primeira linha da matriz.
• Dos elementos localizados na última coluna da matriz.
• Dos elementos localizados na diagonal principal da matriz.
• De todos os elementos da matriz.

A minha tentativa é a seguinte :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int matriz[10][10], q, x, y, pl, uc, sd, st;

printf("Digite o numero de linhas e colunas ");
scanf("%d", &q);

printf("digite os valores da matriz \n");

// escreve a matriz

for (x = 0; x < q; x++) 
    for(y = 0; y < q; y++)
        scanf("%d", &matriz[x][y]);

// mostra a matriz 

for (x = 0; x < q; x++) 
    for(y = 0; y < q; y++)
        printf("%d ", matriz[x][y]);

// soma a primeira linha

for (x = 0; x < q; x++)
    pl += matriz[0][x];
printf(" soma da primeira linha %d", pl);

// soma a ultima coluna

for (y=0; y<q; y++) 
    uc += matriz[y][q];
printf(" soma da ultima coluna %d", uc);

// soma diagonal principal
sd = 0;

for(x=0; x < 10; x++)
    for(y=0;y<10;y++)
      if(x==y)
      sd += matriz[x][y];
printf(" soma da diagonal principal %d", sd);

// soma total

for (x = 0; x < q; x++) 
    for(y = 0; y < q; y++)
        st = matriz[x][y];
printf(" soma total %d", st);

        
return 0;
```

}

O programa roda certinho mas com resultados diferentes do esperado

Answer (score -3):

FIZ UM CÓDIGO COM TODAS AS FUNÇÕES QUE PRECISA PARA OBTER OS RESULTADOS. ESPERO TER AJUDADO. QUALQUER DUVIDA SOBRE O CÓDIGO SÓ PERGUNTA.

---

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

// Função que Ler e Valida o Tamanho da Matriz. Maximo 10.

int lerTamMat(){

```
int tam;

do{
    printf("Digite o Numero de Linhas e Colunas da Matriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);

    if(tam < 1 || tam > MAX){

        printf("\n\tInforme um Numero entre [1 e 10]\n\n");
    }

}while(tam < 1 || tam > MAX);

printf("\n");

return tam;
```

}

// Função que Adiciona os Valores nas Posições da Matriz.

int valoresMat(int i, int j){

```
int num;

printf("Digite o Valor da Posicao [%d][%d]:", i, j);
scanf("%d", &num);

return num;
```

}

// Procedimento para Preencher a Matriz.

void preencherMatriz(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tamMat; j++){

        mat[i][j] = valoresMat(i, j);
    }
}
```

}

// Função para Somar a Primeira Linha da Matriz.

int somaLinha(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
int soma = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){

    soma += mat[0][i];
}

return soma;
```

}

// Função para Somar a Ultima Coluna da Matriz.

int somaColuna(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
int soma = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){

    soma += mat[i][tamMat - 1];
}

return soma;
```

}

// Função para Somar a Diagonal Princiapal da Matriz.

int somaDiagPrincipal(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
int soma;

for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){

    soma += mat[i][i];
}

return soma;
```

}

// Função para Somar Todos os Elementos da Matriz.

int somaTotal(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
int soma;

for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tamMat; j++){

        soma += mat[i][j];
    }
}

return soma;
```

}

// Procedimento para Imprimir os Resultados.

void imprimir(int mat[MAX][MAX], int tamMat){

```
printf("\n\nMATRIZ:\n\n");

for(int i = 0; i < tamMat; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tamMat; j++){

        printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

printf("\nSOMA DA PRIMEIRA LINHA: %d\n", somaLinha(mat, tamMat));

printf("\nSOMA DA ULTIMA COLUNA: %d\n", somaColuna(mat, tamMat));

printf("\nSOMA DA DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL: %d\n", somaDiagPrincipal(mat, tamMat));

printf("\nSOMA DE TODOS OS ELEMENTOS: %d\n", somaTotal(mat, tamMat));
```

}

int main(){

```
int matriz[MAX][MAX], tamMat;

tamMat = lerTamMat();

preencherMatriz(matriz, tamMat);

imprimir(matriz, tamMat);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).